# Squarespace - Display text file instead of downloading it

Tags: squarespace, app-ads.txt

Need your help or advice

I am struggling to figure out how to display a txt file on Squarespace without downloading it.

If you navigate to [www.arcadecloud.com/ads.txt](https://www.arcadecloud.com/ads.txt), the browser will ask you to download the file instead of displaying it. But I need to display it like on this website [www.ToonGoggles.com/ads.txt](https://www.ToonGoggles.com/ads.txt)

If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know. As I understand correctly the webserver is telling the browser to download the file and I need to adjust header to Content-Type text/plain. no clue how to do it.

Comment: upload ads.txt file to another server and redirect URL.

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. I have no idea why your question was downvoted.

Comment: @Felix and OP, did either of you ever find a solution for this? I am having this exact same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this in the future.

I contacted SquareSpace, and they told me this wasn't possible.

> At this time we do not support the ability to upload an ads.txt file
> directly into the root directory of a domain at this time. If this is
> related to Google AdSense, we would advise contact Google AdSense
> support for more information and possible alternatives.   Here is also
> our guide on this for further reference:
>
> https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545597-Can-I-place-advertisements-on-my-site-#toc-google-adsense